# To a meaningful vs To meaningful

Tags: prepositions, articles

1. He can convert a meaningless sentence to **a** meaningful one?
2. He can convert a meaningless sentence to meaningful one.

Will it be okay if we don't add article 'a' after preposition 'to' here? Will it still be correct?

Comment: No it wouldn't be okay. You ***must*** repeat the article in constructions of the general form *[convert / change / alter] **an X** to **a Y*** (regardless of whether ***X*** and/or ***Y*** are adjectivally modified, as for example *convert **an input value** to **an output value***).

Comment: Thank you so much